# sql query to calculate odd and even place digits sum

Tags: sql, oracle

I need a SQL query/function which will find out SUM of digits, which is present in even positions and SUM of digits which is present in odd position.

Example:

If number is `440065385`:

```
x=4+0+6+3+5=18(x is holding sum of odd positions)
y=4+0+5+8=17 (y holds the sum of even positions).
```

Thanks.

Comment: Why would anyone want to program this using SQL? :-|

Comment: Don't use SQL for things it was not designed to do. It's just plain wrong and not performant!

Comment: Are the number of digits fixed? What is the data type of the column?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: No number digits are not fixed. data type is VARCHAR2 (25).
I am using oracle.

Comment: I used below method to find the sum even and odd positrions

Comment: DECLARE
 v_string VARCHAR2(25) := '440065385';
 X number(25):=0;
 Y number(25):=0;
 BEGIN
 FOR r IN 1..LENGTH( v_string)
 LOOP
 IF MOD( r,2) <> 0 THEN
 X :=  X+SUBSTR( v_string, r, 1 );
 ELSE
 Y := Y+SUBSTR( v_string, r, 1 );
 END IF; 
END LOOP;

Comment: don't post code in comments. edit your question (and explain the problem you have with that code, don't just throw code at us without an explanation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can mimic an iteration using level and connect by to achieve the same

```
with iterate as 
(select level as i from dual connect by level <=25)
 select
       table1.column1, 
       sum(decode(mod(iterate.i,2),0,substr(table1.column1,iterate.i,1))) sum_even,
       sum(decode(mod(iterate.i,2),1,substr(table1.column1,iterate.i,1))) sum_old
 from table1 ,iterate 
 where iterate.i <=length(table1.column1)
 group by table1.column1
```

Answer (score 1):

You could join your table with a numbers table, to split all digits into rows, then sum odds and even position digits separately.

```
with positions(position) as 
    (select level from dual connect by level <=25
    ),
digits as
    (
    select 
        t1.v,
        n.position ,
        cast(substr(t1.v ,length(t1.v) - n.position + 1, 1) as int) as digit
    from my_table t1 left join positions n
    on n.position <= length(t1.v)
    )
select
    v,
    sum(case when mod(position,2)=0 then digit else 0 end) as evensum,
    sum(case when mod(position,2)=1 then digit else 0 end) as oddsum
from
    digits
group by
    v
```

Test [Sql Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9bb06/5), the result:

```
V           EVENSUM ODDSUM
440065385   17      18
```